# The authentication session doesn't behave as intended when wrapped with 'authenticate("auth-session")' in my app

Tags: kotlin, authentication, session, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

Here is my main class in which I configure all the components of the application:

```
internal fun Application.module() {

    install(Koin) {
        modules(getKoinModule())
    }

    val localSource by inject<LocalSource>()

    install(Routing) {
        api(application = application, localSource = localSource)
    }

    configureMonitoring()
    configureAuth()
    configureSession()

    install(StatusPages) {
        exception<Throwable> { call, cause ->
            call.respond(cause.toString())
        }
    }

    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json()
    }
}
```

The problem just lies in the new plugins (**Authentication**, **Sessions**), which I basically did based on the documentation([OAuth](https://ktor.io/docs/oauth.html), [Sessions](https://ktor.io/docs/sessions.html)).

Here is their code:

```
fun Application.configureAuth() {
    this.log.info("configureAuth")
    install(Authentication) {
        session<UserSession>(name = "auth-session") {
            this@configureAuth.log.info("this session: ${this.name}")
            validate { session ->
                this@configureAuth.log.info("User session: authorized $session")
                session
            }
            challenge {
                this@configureAuth.log.info("User session: unauthorized")
                call.respondRedirect("/unauthorized")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
fun Application.configureSession() {
    this.log.info("configureSession")
    install(Sessions) {
        val secretEncryptKey = hex("00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff")
        val secretAuthKey = hex("02030405060708090a0b0c") //6819b57a326945c1968f45236589
        cookie<UserSession>(
            name = "USER_SESSION",
            storage = directorySessionStorage(File(".sessions"))
        ) {
            transform(SessionTransportTransformerEncrypt(secretEncryptKey, secretAuthKey))
        }
    }
}
```

I use the following dependency

```
"io.ktor:ktor-server-auth:2.0.3"
"io.ktor:ktor-server-sessions:2.0.3"
```

And now in places where I need to add `authenticate("auth-session")` for example here:

```
fun Routing.authorizedRoute() {
    val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)
    logger.debug("authorizedRoute here")
    authenticate("auth-session") {
        route("/authorized") {
            get {
                logger.debug("authorizedRoute authorized GET")
                call.respond(
                    message = ApiResponse(success = true),
                    status = HttpStatusCode.OK
                )
            }

            post {
                logger.debug("authorizedRoute authorized POST")
                call.respond(
                    message = ApiResponse(success = true),
                    status = HttpStatusCode.OK
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of getting into the router `/authorized`, I get into the **challenge** method and the session itself does not pass validation, although it was created in the sessions folder.
[image]

**UPD:**

When I try to debug the `onAuthenticate` method in **io.ktor.server.auth**, I see that it does not save my session
[image]

Also here is the code where I set the value for this session: https://gist.github.com/mnewlive/1933134a58a950525f949aed23c31d5e

Comment: Can you please share the code where you create a session (`call.sessions.set(...)`)?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman sure, here it is https://gist.github.com/mnewlive/1933134a58a950525f949aed23c31d5e .

Comment: @AlekseiTirman  in this code, I have a redirect to the /authorized route, but for some reason it gets into the `challenge` in Authentication plugin(fun Application.configureAuth) and does not validate my session

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your problem with the modified code https://gist.github.com/Stexxe/466c80816612bcb0d7a07b1b5d766b52

Comment: @AlekseiTirman when I go to /token_verification -> /authorized, I have no logs that I got inside some of the routes /authorized and immediately get into the challenge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that it was not possible to save cookies received from the server in response to requests.

So i solve it with next code:

```
install(HttpCookies) {
    storage = AcceptAllCookiesStorage()
}
```